oracle create table and insert data
I know you can create a table then insert data like this. Is there a way to create your table and insert data at the same time?
CREATE TABLE people(
  id int,
  name varchar(55),
  status int,
  phone varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO people
(id, name, status, phone)
VALUES (2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234');
INSERT INTO people
(id, name, status, phone)
VALUES (7, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234');
INSERT INTO people
(id, name, status, phone)
VALUES (3, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234');
INSERT INTO people
(id, name, status, phone)
VALUES (22, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234');
INSERT INTO people
(id, name, status, phone)
VALUES (8, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234');

INSERT INTO people VALUES
(7, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'),
(22, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'),
(8, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'),
(15, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'),
(5, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234');

select * from people where id in (8, 22, 15, 5, 7); 

SELECT id, name, status, phone
FROM people
WHERE status = 1;

https://dbfiddle.uk/CdD1-e57

Use CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT .... If you want to set the data-types in the SELECT then use CAST.
CREATE TABLE people(id, name, status, phone) AS
SELECT CAST(7      AS INT),
       CAST('Mary' AS VARCHAR2(55)),
       CAST(0      AS INT),
       CAST('555-111-1234' AS VARCHAR2(55))
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234' FROM DUAL;

fiddle

Is there an advantage of either method?

It looks like casting is mandatory if you want to give it to have a type? https://dbfiddle.uk/OkpVKN19 , https://dbfiddle.uk/Ian2-wP5, https://dbfiddle.uk/EERhquJK Do you know why you have to cast?

@noobprogrammer1987 CAST is not necessary - however, if you do not use it the Oracle will infer the data type from the data and that may not be what you want fiddle.

As for setting the column names in the CREATE TABLE or in the SELECT, they are just different alternatives for the same thing. If you do both then the identifiers specified in the CREATE TABLE line will take precedence over aliases in the SELECT.

I get it you will have trouble later on if you want to add a long name like Jackson or Edward. Same thing if you have a long international phone number you want to add.
